# Django giving me no reverse match error

Tags: python, django, django-views

NoReverseMatch at /errorcodes/error_codes/2
Reverse for 'relatedpartsview' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['errorcodes\/error_codes\/relatedparts\/(?P[^/]+)$']

Currently I am trying to pass a PK into my link as an argument.  However, I keep getting no reverse match.  I have added a redirect statement, but that doesn't seem to be resolving the issue.

views.py

```
class RelatedPartsListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'related_parts_list'
model = models.ErrorCodes
template_name = 'related_parts_list.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # xxx will be available in the template as the related objects
    context = super(ErrorCodeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['relatedparts'] = RelatedParts.objects.filter(related_error_code=self.get_object())
    return context

    return redirect('RelatedPartsListView', pk='pk')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path(r'error_codes/',views.ErrorCodeList.as_view(), name='errorcodelist'),
path(r'error_codes/<pk>',views.ErrorCodeView.as_view(), name='errorcodeview'),
path(r'error_codes/relatedparts/<pk>',views.RelatedPartsListView.as_view(), name='relatedpartsview')
```

]

Link

```
{% url 'errorcodes:relatedpartsview' %}
```

Update:  I am getting a 'RelatedPartsListView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

class RelatedPartsListView(ListView):

```
context_object_name = 'related_parts_list'
model = models.ErrorCodes
template_name = 'related_parts_list.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # xxx will be available in the template as the related objects
    obj = super(RelatedPartsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    obj = RelatedParts.objects.filter(related_error_code=self.get_object())
    return redirect('related_parts_list', obj.pk)
```

Comment: Try to use the name in the `redirect` function exactly as given in `urls.py` using the right capitalization: `'relatedpartsview'`.

Comment: Your `relatedpartsview` URL pattern requires a value for `pk` but you're not providing one in your `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: how would I insert this?

Comment: tried yours klaus, no go, although I thought that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url you are trying to use `{% url %}` without passing your `pk` which is wht that url relies on. You can reference the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/

So, you should be passing your object (the one with the pk) to your template through the context. Then you can access that object's pk value. So, you will have something like this.

```
{% url 'relatedpartsviewurl' obj.pk %}
```

Edit: Your redirect also does not make any sense and you have two return statements right after each other which makes absolutely no sense.

Edit: Okay, so you need to make your template name in your return redirect the exact same as what is shown in your urls where `name=` . Next, you need to get rid of your context, rather store your filter as a variable such as `obj`. Then for your `pk` in your redirect, just reference that variable like so `redirect('template_name', obj.pk)`

---

Edit: CLASS BASED VIEW (idk if works)
Your list view.

```
class RelatedPartsListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'related_parts_list'
    model = models.ErrorCodes
    template_name = 'related_parts_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RelatedPartsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['relatedparts'] = RelatedParts.objects.filter(related_error_code=1)
        return context
```

Replace the relatedparts url with this.

```
re_path(r'^error_codes/relatedparts/?P<parts_id>[0-9]+',views.RelatedPartsListView.as_view(), name='related_parts_view')
```

Make your link like this.

```
{% url 'errorcodes:related_parts_view' 1 %}
```

---

Edit: FUNCTION BASED VIEW

views.py

```
def related_parts_view(request, error_code):
    parts = RelatedParts.objects.filter(related_error_code=error_code)
    context = {
        'relatedparts': parts
    }
    return render(request, 'path/to/my/template.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
re_path(r'^error_codes/relatedparts/?P<error_code>[0-9]+', errorcodes.views.related_parts_view, name='related_parts_view')
```

other_template.html

```
<a href="{% url errorcodes:related_parts_view' error_code.pk %}">Go to Related Parts</a>
```

template.html

```
{% for part in relatedparts %}
    {{ part.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Updated at the top

Comment: This is a relational table if that helps

Comment: Ill help some more later..I will write something up once my headache goes away.

Comment: @lakerskill Do you happen to be new to Django, just out of curiosity.

Comment: I am very new!  Just started a couple months back.

Comment: @lakerskill Okay in that case, I strongly believe that CBV (Class Based Views) are not the way to go. FBV (Function Based Views) are very literal and explicit, meaning there is no "MAGIC" like CBV has. Every tutorial I have looked at spent so much time on CBV and I could never get them to do what I wanted them to do. So, I have been using FBV for over a year now and have a production multi-tenant Django app hosted on Heroku. [Here is a link with more explanation](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/03/21/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views.html). I recommend FBV as newbie.

Comment: Lol I've already been heading down that path!  Still not working but I think I'm getting closer.

Comment: @lakerskill sorry for the mess, but I gave you the CBV and FBV. Pretty sure the FBV will work so long as you import things you need like the render, and import your models accordingly. Basically, if I am on some `other_template.html` I should click the link which will have already passed in an error code object from that view for `error_code` (You can hard code a # to test it). That will call `related_parts_view` and return your list of parts with that `error_code` you passed in. Then `template.html` renders every part in that `context` you passed through.

Comment: just did that.  Still have a reversematch error.  I appreciate it though

Comment: Sorry, fixed the urls.py. Are you using a `reverse()` anywhere?

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /errorcodes/error_codes/3
Reverse for 'related_parts_view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['errorcodes\\/error_codes/relatedparts/?P<error_code>[0-9]+']

Comment: The site is now rendering with nothing in it!  Progress!

Comment: now receiving 'RelatedPartsListView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Comment: Don't use the get object. Just pass in an actual value for that field. Then you can understand how to put a variable in it.

Comment: context['relatedparts'] = RelatedParts.objects.filter(related_error_code=ErrorCodes.name) but this didn't work

Comment: It would really help if you posted your models and your templates haha. Im working on so little here hahaha. I can't really state whether your references to objects need to be different because idk what kind of fields they are.

Comment: Haha I am glad you got it, I feel like I did not really help you rhe way you needed haha. Get some rest!